# How to access spring jpa references in json

Tags: json, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have two entitys, A and B. Lets say, that, A has some fields (name, location). B has some fields too + a `@ManyToOne` relationship to A.

Now if I run my app, I can see the entitys and their valus in *...myDomain/api* and specific entitys in *...myDomain/api/A* for example. Now if look at *...myDomain/api/B/1*, I can see B-s values + under _links a reference to A. How can I get A to already be as a value in B, not a link.

End result should look smth like this:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "B" : [ {
      "id" : 1,
      "someData" : "data",
      "otherData" : "other",
      "A" : {
         "name": "myName",
         "location": "myLoc"
    } ]
```

**UPDATE**

```
@Entity
@Data //lombok
public class A extends SuperClass{
 private String name;
 private String location;
}

@Entity
@Data
public class B extends SuperClass {
  private String someData; 
  private String otherData;
  @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private A a;
}

public class SuperClass implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  protected long id;
}
```

Both entitys have a simple repository interface which extend CrudRepository.

**UPDATE II**

Now if I add `@RestResourece( exported = false )` tag after `@ManyToOne` tag, I get the A entity "exposed" and I can access the data. But now, doing a POST on my B entity, I can't access it anymore because B isn't found by `Resource<B>` anymore. Why is that so?

Comment: Where's your code?!

Comment: please share what you tried so far

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/2.6.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#_customizing_the_representation

Comment: The documentation about the problem is quit little. An example would be useful.