# Spring RepositoryRestController with excerptProjection

Tags: spring, spring-data, entity, spring-data-jpa, hateoas

I have defined a @Projection for my Spring Data entity as described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.excerpting-commonly-accessed-data)

For the same reasons as described there. When I do `GET` request, everything is returned as expected. But when I do a `POST` request, the projection won't work. Following the example provided above, "Address" is shown as a URL under Links and is not exposed the way it is with `GET` request.

How to get it exposed the same way?

I created a class with `@RepositoryRestController` where I can catch the `POST` method. If I simply return the entity, it is without links. If I return it as a resource, the links are there, but "Address" is also a link. If I remove the `GET` method from my controller, the default behavior is as described above.

**UPDATE**

My entities are same as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178483/how-to-access-spring-jpa-references-in-json) `A`, `B` and `SuperClass` except I don't have *fetch* defined in my `@ManyToOne`
My controller looks like this:

```
@RepositoryRestController
public class BRepositoryRestController {

  private final BRepository bRepository;

  public BRepositoryRestController(BRepository bRepository) {
    this.bRepository = bRepository;
  }


  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/bs")
  public 
  ResponseEntity<?> post(@RequestBody Resource<B> bResource) {
    B b= bRepository.save(bResource.getContent());
    BProjection result = bRepository.findById(b.getId());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new Resource<>(result));
  }
}
```

And my repository looks like this:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = BProjection.class)
public interface BRepository extends BaseRepository<B, Long> {
  @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"a"})
  BProjection findById(Long id);
}
```

And my projection looks like this:

```
@Projection(types = B.class)
public interface BProjection extends SuperClassProjection {
  A getA();
  String getSomeData();
  String getOtherData();      
}
```

And SuperClassProjection looks like this:

```
@Projection(types = SuperClass.class)
public interface SuperClassProjection {
  Long getId();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the custom @RepositoryRestController POST method you should also return the projection. For example:

```
@Projection(name = "inlineAddress", types = { Person.class }) 
public interface InlineAddress {
    String getFirstName();
    String getLastName();
    @Value("#{target.address}") 
    Address getAddress(); 
}

public interface PersonRepo extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
    InlineAddress findById(Long personId); 
}

@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> post(...) {
    //... posting a person
    InlineAddress inlineAddress = bookRepo.findById(person.getId());
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new Resource<>(inlineAddress));
}
```

**UPDATE**

I've corrected my code above and the code from the question:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = BProjection.class)
public interface BRepository extends CrudRepository<B, Long> {   
  BProjection findById(Long id);
}

@Projection(types = B.class)
public interface BProjection {
    @Value("#{target.a}")
    A getA();
    String getSomeData();
    String getOtherData();
}
```

Then all works fine.

POST request body:

```
{
    "name": "b1",
    "someData": "someData1",
    "otherData": "otherData",
    "a": {
        "name": "a1"
    }
}
```

Response body:

```
{
    "a": {
        "name": "a1"
    },
    "someData": "someData1",
    "otherData": "otherData",
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/bs/1{?projection}",
            "templated": true
        }
    }
}
```

See working [example](https://github.com/Cepr0/restdemo/tree/master/src/main/java/restsdemo/example17)

Comment: Hmm, my repository is extending CRUDRepository. And I'm getting an error: `query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list...`

Comment: @JamesLinux add the code of your model and repo to your question - it will be easier for me to correct my code.Nevertheless main thought is to return a projection in controller method.

Comment: It's the same as in the example. I have defined a `@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`. My projection is also the same.

Comment: In one of my previous question, I have defined them like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178483/how-to-access-spring-jpa-references-in-json)

Comment: @JamesLinux in [reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections) `Address` has a `OneToOne` reference. Change your code and try again..

Comment: But I need a @ManyToOne reference. And the error remained the same.